# Artifactory CLI copy Issue

Tags: command-line-interface, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have recently started working in artifactory (4.4.0). I have successfully configured artifactory cli to upload & download binaries from artifactory by commandline.

jfrog rt dl XXX/*.zip

but 
When i try to do perform copy and move opertation, im facing below.
jfrog rt cp XXX/* YYYY/ --login=** --password=***

Artifactory response: **400 Bad Request.**

When i do a dryrun, it works perfectly but when i do at realtime, im getting the above ERROR.

Comment: Please  check the Artifactory log for the exact error. If the error isn't self-explanatory, please paste the relevant piece of the log to the question.

Comment: when i execute the copy command, I can see the details in the request.log file,     201610239XX|6|REQUEST|10.10.10.22|admin|POST|api/copy/REPO/folder/test.txt|HTTP/1.1|400|0

Comment: Please check the Artifactory log, not the request log.

Comment: when i execute jfrog rt dl  REPO/test/* (download command)  in the log i can see it ends with *****|HTTP/1.1|200|0   but  in the case of ( copy command ) jfrog rt cp REPO/test/* TAG/test/, log ends with *****|HTTP/1.1|400|0

Comment: That's still a request log. Please check Arifactory log.